# Visual Studio 2017 change cshtml without recompile

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2017

When I change something in cshtml views in a compiled project, during debug, i got

*InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SZArray' to type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol'*

error and I need to stop debugger, and re-run the solution.

I remember that few months ago i can normally change .cshtml file and see modification without recompiling.

What is changed?